# communication between 2 arduino crash when external power supply is plugged

Tags: arduino, power-supply, i2c

i have one arduino mega that communicates with one arduino leonardo.

the leonardo controls some motors (mega tell to the leonardo how many step to do... leonardo is a coprocessor for the motor in other words).

for testing i try to send the number 20 from the mega to the leonardo. i sent the number as a sequence of char, with 2 char of haeder so in this case i'm sending 'M>0020' as 6 char (6 byte). leonardo send the status (ready/busy) back to the master through the pin4 (this is to avoid the interrputs in Wire.h that can add delay in the motor code if the master require data to the slave).

communication seems ok, but if i plug power supply (12V) communication crashes. if i reset the mega the leonardo read 11049 (i haven't the board there, could be a different number, but it is always the same), the recives for 5/6 times the correct number 20, then communication crash, and mega crash.

i tried to unplug every motor-related stuff from leonardo, so i have only 4 wire:

1. common ground
2. sda
3. slc
4. the wire for the state (ready/busy) of the slave.

the problems occurs every time i plugged the power supply. sometimes it happens that the problem occurs even without 12v external power (so onlu usb cable that power leonardo) after some time (half an hour)

the 2 arduino boards are linked with a 8m cable (i've used the tester and the cable seems ok, it was a cable for a lan network).

any suggestion?

Comment: I think 8m is too long for un-driven I2C bus. I'm guessing that when you plug in the 12V supply it is connecting the ground loop, generating a some current and interfering with the I2C signals. Additionally the noise from the 12V supply will cause some current in the ground wire as it will be varying from the ground of the other supply, causing interference with the I2C lines.

Comment: Try - shorter cable; powering both devices from one power supply (extra power cable); slowing down I2C bus; change comms to RS-232 or better yet - XBee. XBee is wireless - win.

Comment: what other protocol can i try to use for sending a number (from 0 to 1000) between several arduino boardswith that distance? i'm looking for the easiest solution.

Comment: More than two boards? i really like XBee stuff because it is wireless, but it might not be the easiest. I think maybe try slowing down the I2C speed.

Comment: Change i2c speed: http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php/topic,12518.0.html   this page: http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php/topic,16793.0.html says you have to "delete the files 
hardware/libraries/Wire/Wire.o 
hardware/libraries/Wire/utility/twi.o"

Comment: slow down to? i don't have xbee boards and stuffs need to work in 2 days.. i'm considering using tx/rx.. but i'm not sure if it is easy to add more arduino.. but slow down i2c seems a solution!

Comment: 10kHz, 1KHz just keep lowering? I havent actually needed to do it myself - my I2C lines are about 1cm long - so this is some educated guessing. Hopefully someone will come along and answer with a better method.  BTW - can you check if it has crashed and restart the I2C bit? Might buy you some time if it has to be ready in two days...

Comment: oh - what happens if you use a another, separate, ground cable and cut the ground wire of your existing cable at one end? so two cables - one with comms and one with ground.

Comment: Where does the 12V supply plug in? What is it for? (the motors?) If you have the 12V present at startup does it work? A schematic would help here. What value pullups are you using for the I2C lines?

Comment: draw a schematics of how both boards are powered - you might find a problem yourself instantly. Maybe 12V power supply is too noisy - try putting a cap across it, BTW are you sure your power supply is OK? On another note - 8m for naked I2C is too much, you might damage your boards in case on electromagnetic event (big motor, lightning, etc). If you need to connect one or more devices in distance, consider using UART over RS485 transceivers like LTC485.

Comment: power supply is plugged to arduino and the motors get power from vin. BUT i have also try to plug only the motors.. but the problem is the same

Comment: i have slowed down and it seems to work! maybe add as answer so i can accept it

Comment: nice! glad that it worked. Just a thought to make it more robust - can you add some kind of lock up checking? i.e. no message received in 10 sec, restart I2C?

Comment: this is a problem because if an arduino is plugged but switched off it cause master to crash!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: this answer is based on the comments above.

Possibly the cause of the problem is:
* Long I2C cable length, combined with
* Different power supplies causing current to flow in the ground wire of the cable, causing noise on the I2C lines.

The solution that worked was to reduce the I2C bus speed. It is usually 100kHz but one can reduce it to 10kHz by making the following code changes (taken from http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php/topic,12518.0.html)

Modify hardware/libraries/Wire/utility/twi.h:

Old:

```
#ifndef TWI_FREQ
#define TWI_FREQ 100000L
#endif
```

New:

```
#ifndef TWI_FREQ
#define TWI_FREQ 10000L  /* 10kHz */
#define PRESCALER_10KHZ 4
#endif
```

Modify hardware/libraries/Wire/utility/twi.c

Old:

```
cbi(TWSR, TWPS0);
cbi(TWSR, TWPS1);

TWBR = ((CPU_FREQ / TWI_FREQ) - 16) / 2;
```

New:

```
/* Select 4 as the prescaler value - see page 239 of the data sheet */
cbi(TWSR, TWPS1);
sbi(TWSR, TWPS0);

TWBR = ((CPU_FREQ / TWI_FREQ) - 16) / 2 / PRESCALER_10KHZ;
/*
  The documentation in twi.c is assuming a prescaler value of 1.  
  The actual equation (data sheet page 218) is 
  SCL Frequency = CPU Clock Frequency / (16 + (2 * TWBR * prescaler))
  For a rate of 10kHz with a clock speed of 16MHz, TWBR is 198.
*/
```

This post (http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php/topic,16793.0.html) also advises that ".. you also have to the delete the files:

- hardware/libraries/Wire/Wire.o
- hardware/libraries/Wire/utility/twi.o"

to make sure the changes are recompiled.

Comment: ok now a little question: has this method got some side effects?

Comment: I2C is synchronous, so it could probably be clocked as slow as you like. I think the only side effect is the speed of communications will be slower. But you are using 10kHz and only sending a few characters so this should not be a problem.